# referenceerror in underscore js template

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js

i am using backbonejs with node js trying to pass variable from backbone view to template(html file). function for rendering view template is like this :

```
render: function(event){
        var compiled_template = _.template( $("#results-template").html() );
        console.log(myPhoto.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(compiled_template(myPhoto.toJSON()));    
        return this;
    }
```

myPhoto having a value :

```
{
        src: 'placeholder.jpg',
        title: 'an image placeholder',
        coordinates: [0,0],
        tags:  ['untagged'],
        location: 'home'
 }
```

and in html file :

```
<script id="results-template" type="text/template">               
        <h2><%= title %></h2>
        <p>testing....</p>
    </script>
```

when i am execute it gives an error like

```
ReferenceError: c:\trello\testApp/views/test.html:19
    17|     <script id="results-template" type="text/template">       
    18|        
 >> 19|         <h2><%= title %></h2>        
    20|         <p>testing....</p>
    21|     </script>
    22|     

title is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (c:\trello\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:203:1))
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\trello\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:201:15)
    at ServerResponse._render (c:\trello\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:425:21)
    at ServerResponse.render (c:\trello\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:318:17)
    at c:\trello\testApp\test.js:23:16
    at callbacks (c:\trello\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:272:11)
    at param (c:\trello\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:246:11)
    at pass (c:\trello\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (c:\trello\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:4)
    at Object.handle (c:\trello\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:45:10)
```

how to solve this???

Comment: yes it is working but when i excute using node.js then it gives me error.

Comment: I use node.js/ejs on the server side and backbone.js on the client side. Both server side and client side use the same templating style. So the problem is, if I put template code meant for the client inside a template is not get's parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all your photos have a title? Empty properties can cause this error. You can fix this by adding default values (empty strings for example) in your backbone Model class.